# Use mysqldump to back up the database on the remote server

Tags: mysql, remote-server

Condition: program server ip address eg.ip1:192.168.1.13;
           remote database server ip address eg.ip2:102.119.128.34;
           mysql version in ip1:5.6.29

Running command:first of all,I backup ip2 database in ip1 use mysqldump,the command is: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h102.119.128.34 -u******** -p****** backupdatabase | gzip > info.sql.gz`,but in the file of info.sql.gz,only the structure of the table in the database is backup and the data in the database table is not backup.

[image]

I don't know why occure this phenomenon.

Comment: Check that the user has at least the SELECT permission on the database you try to backup.

Comment: Best command I ever learned: http://christiank.org/wp/2010/12/pipe-a-gzipped-mysql-dump-over-ssh/ you can remove the ssh part... or not... your choice...